# Getting value from string by index

Tags: php, arrays, json, json-deserialization

I have a string of data formatted like so:

```
[{"pr_a_w":"10","pr_a_we":"10","pr_c_w":"10","pr_c_we":"10"},{"pr_a_w":"20","pr_a_we":"20","pr_c_w":"20","pr_c_we":"20"},{"pr_a_w":"111","pr_a_we":"11","pr_c_w":"111","pr_c_we":"111"}]
```

The string doesn't have any index/numbers like a regular array would and I'm finding it difficult to extract individual values e.g. with a regular array I could use:

```
$string[0]["pr_a_w"]
```

To get the first instance of "pr_a_w" and I could use:

```
$string[1]["pr_a_w"]
```

To get the second instance etc.

Is it possible to get single values from this string based on their number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is valid JSON (*serialized array of objects*), so you could use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to translate the serialized data into a native PHP array:

```
$array = json_decode('[{"pr_a_w":"10","pr_a_we":"10","pr_c_w":"10","pr_c_we":"10"},{"pr_a_w":"20","pr_a_we":"20","pr_c_w":"20","pr_c_we":"20"},{"pr_a_w":"111","pr_a_we":"11","pr_c_w":"111","pr_c_we":"111"}]',true);
```

`$array` will then allow you to do exactly what you stated you'd like to do above.

```
$array[0]["pr_a_w"]; // will give you 10
$array[1]["pr_a_w"]; // will give you 10
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help! that turned out to be a lot easier than I expected!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, No need to access with array index. You will get error if you access wrong index.

```
$json_arr= json_decode('[{"pr_a_w":"10","pr_a_we":"10","pr_c_w":"10","pr_c_we":"10"},{"pr_a_w":"20","pr_a_we":"20","pr_c_w":"20","pr_c_we":"20"},{"pr_a_w":"111","pr_a_we":"11","pr_c_w":"111","pr_c_we":"111"}]',true);

foreach($json_arr as $row){
    echo $row['pr_a_w']."<br>";
}
```